# Which can be better in automation framework designing for an organisation, Python or Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, python

I want to start automation testing with selenium webdriver(need to design the framework for the same), so which would be better to start with Java or Python ?

Comment: If there were an objective answer, the alternative simply wouldn't exist. The best option will depend on your context: Your testing problem, your skills, your constraints, etc. I edit your question explaining in more depth your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with either language ?  Are there co-workers or mentors that use either of these languages ?  These are the types of questions you need to answer.  Either language works fine with Selenium.  If you are starting from scratch with no resources, I guess I would start with Python.  The learning curve should be easier and the tutorials on the web should be more recent.  Disclaimer --- I prefer Java but have been using it for a long time.